# How to return back to the error place after dealing with it in Application_Error?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

the question is as the headline describes. this is a general question that i hoped could improved anyone error-handling process.

In some general errors I can fix the problem in Application_Error and then return to last place as nothing happens. but I need something better then Response.Redirect() which also refresh the page/

and as a personal note, it is good to come back here after 3 years of exile :)

Comment: by the way, part of the fixing is of course : Server.ClearError();

Comment: also it is important to be careful not to get into infinite loop in this situation, raising a flag in a session variable that you already been here and try to dealt with the problem is almost a must.